# Why does MySQL prefer ENUM('N','Y') over BOOL?

Tags: mysql, types, database-design, space-efficiency

Today I noticed that the tables of the `mysql` database in a default MySQL 8 installation use the type `ENUM('N','Y')` where I would expect them to use `BOOL`. For example, see the output of `DESCRIBE user`. The same pattern is followed elsewhere, such as the `db` table.

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+
| Field                    | Type                              | Null | Key | Default               | Extra |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+
| Host                     | char(255)                         | NO   | PRI |                       |       |
| User                     | char(32)                          | NO   | PRI |                       |       |
| Select_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Insert_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Update_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Delete_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Drop_priv                | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Reload_priv              | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Shutdown_priv            | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Process_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| File_priv                | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Grant_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| References_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Index_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Alter_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Show_db_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Super_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_tmp_table_priv    | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Lock_tables_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Execute_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Repl_slave_priv          | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Repl_client_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_view_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Show_view_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_routine_priv      | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Alter_routine_priv       | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_user_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Event_priv               | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Trigger_priv             | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_tablespace_priv   | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| ssl_type                 | enum('','ANY','X509','SPECIFIED') | NO   |     |                       |       |
| ssl_cipher               | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| x509_issuer              | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| x509_subject             | blob                              | NO   |     | NULL                  |       |
| max_questions            | int unsigned                      | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_updates              | int unsigned                      | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_connections          | int unsigned                      | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| max_user_connections     | int unsigned                      | NO   |     | 0                     |       |
| plugin                   | char(64)                          | NO   |     | caching_sha2_password |       |
| authentication_string    | text                              | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| password_expired         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| password_last_changed    | timestamp                         | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| password_lifetime        | smallint unsigned                 | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| account_locked           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Create_role_priv         | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Drop_role_priv           | enum('N','Y')                     | NO   |     | N                     |       |
| Password_reuse_history   | smallint unsigned                 | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| Password_reuse_time      | smallint unsigned                 | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| Password_require_current | enum('N','Y')                     | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
| User_attributes          | json                              | YES  |     | NULL                  |       |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------+------+-----+-----------------------+-------+
```

Why have they designed the tables like this? Should I also use enums rather than bools in my own tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference internally, they both store the value as a small integer. Using `ENUM` makes queries use more human-friendly values Y/N instead of 1/0, without requiring you to write something like:

```
SELECT CASE index_priv WHEN 0 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
```

Comment: I see that you're right, but I still don't really understand. Wouldn't statements get more complex? Wouldn't `index_priv` need to be replaced by `index_priv = 'Y'` in any conditionals? For example, your query could be `IF(index_priv, 'Y', 'N')`.

Comment: It depends on what you're optimizing for, display or testing.

Answer (score 1):

> Why have they designed the tables like this?

This (with NOT NULL restriction) allows only 2 listed values. Whereas BOOLEAN is mapped to TINYINT(1) and allows another values without additional CHECK constraint. Also ENUM allows to use both string-type and integer values while assign/retrieve/compare/process (depends on expression context). Also the value output is performed in human-readable text, not encoded numeric value.

From the other side, for `enum('N','Y')` the value `N` is mapped to numeric 1 and `Y` to numeric 2 which can be incomfortable.

Comment: I think the first enum is 0, not 1.

Comment: @RickJames No. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29e5d8e79f9b66fbc1bb9bb685d0e87e See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html "Index Values for Enumeration Literals"